# Data structured

Tags: java, dictionary

I am trying to implement in java a Map that has two keys and maintains a set as a value. Please see the code bellow. However, there seems to be a bug in the insertion method and I'm struggling to find it. It would be great if someone could point me to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

```
Map<Key1, Map<Key2, Set<Value>>> map;

public PairHashMapSet() {
map = new HashMap<Key1, Map<Key2, Set<Value>>>();
}

public Set<Value> safeGet(final Key1 key1, final Key2 key2) {
  if (!map.containsKey(key1) || (!map.get(key1).containsKey(key2))) {
     Map<Key2, Set<Value>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
     Set<Value> mySet = new HashSet<>();
     map2.put(key2, mySet);
     map.put(key1, map2);
 }
 return map.get(key1).get(key2);
}

 public void put(Key1 key1, Key2 key2, Value value) {
   safeGet(key1, key2).add(value);
 }
 public Set<Value> get(Key1 key1, Key2 key2) {
   return map.get(key1).get(key2);
}
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: you always re-create map2 even when map2 already exists, only because key2 is not present in it.

Comment: If key1 or key2 are not present, map2 is created as well as the Set to contain the values.  I'm not sure what you mean @f1sh

Comment: Those 2 cases should be handled separately. Imagine what happens if you first `put(A, B, x)` and then `put(A, C, y)`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if this is the *only* bug, but I'd start by looking at the logic in your "safe get" method.

```
if either
    the outer map doesn't have an entry for key1
  OR
    the outer map has an entry for key1, whose value is a map that doesn't have an entry for key2
then
  create an empty set S
  create an empty map M2
  set (key2 => S) in M2
  set (key1 => M2) in the outer map
end if
```

Does it seem right, if the outer map contains an entry for key1, to replace the map referenced by key1 just because the old one didn't contain an entry for key2?